# ObjectDisposedException when creating user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, objectdisposedexception, usermanager

I'm getting an error when I try to create a user. I got it at `line 15` in the following code.

```
1  public async void AddOrganisationAdmin()
2    {
3        
4        String OrganisationName = Request["OrganisationName"];
5        Debug.Print(OrganisationName);
6        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
7        model.Email = "admin@" + OrganisationName;
8        model.Organisation = OrganisationName;
9        model.Password = "adminPassword!1";
10       model.ConfirmPassword = "adminPassword!1";
11       model.Role = "Organisation Administrator";
12
13
14       var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Organisation = model.Organisation, Role = model.Role };
15       IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
16   }
```

The error is:

```
An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but 
was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

What object is disposed? These lines are a copy of the default register function in a asp.net mvc 5 project, so what am I doing wrong?

I'm calling the function from an ajax post like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/Account/AddOrganisationAdmin",
      type: 'POST',
      data: { OrganisationName : "@CompanyName"},
      success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
             console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(xhr);
      }
});
```

I get into the function and I have the correct name.

Comment: do you have your own implementation of `IDisposable` or finalizier?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh No, I do not have my own implementation.

Comment: can you show the`CreateAsync` method?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I'm using the asp.net entity stuff. Here is a little explanation of the createasync https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497540%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh it's probably your `DbContext` why don't you put a watch on it?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos I'm not exactly sure how to put a watch on the DbContext..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of tacos_tacos_tacos made me look into dbcontext a bit and after a trail and error period I got the following

```
1    public void AddOrganisationAdmin()
2    {
3        
4        String OrganisationName = Request["OrganisationName"];
5        Debug.Print(OrganisationName);
6        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
7        model.Email = "admin@" + OrganisationName + ".com";
8        model.Organisation = OrganisationName;
9        model.Password = "adminPassword!1";
10       model.ConfirmPassword = "adminPassword!1";
11       model.Role = "Organisation Admin";
12       Promato.Models.ApplicationDbContext dbcontext = new Promato.Models.ApplicationDbContext();
13        
14       var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Organisation = model.Organisation, Role = model.Role };
15       user.PasswordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.Password);
16       user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
17       dbcontext.Users.Add(user);
18       dbcontext.SaveChanges();
19   }
```

This code is working for me. A user is added to the .mdf and I can login:)